# R docker image size is getting more than 2 gb. How to remove unused packages?

Tags: r, docker

R docker image size is getting more than *2GB*. How to remove unused packages?

I am using Java+R and creating docker image.
but while running jar we are using a library which is coming with transitive dependencies and my docker image is getting larger.
Below are the libraries I am using.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("lumi")

source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("affy")

source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("affyPLM")

source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biobase")
```

I am looking for a utility which can help me reduce the docker size.

Comment: We need more details. Are you talking about a container that you have running? Is this an image you are building on top of the base R image? Just the default image? Are you talking about the size of the image, or the size of the container running that image?

Comment: @avigil the container which is using base R using multiple packages which are increasing the container size as well as performance.

Comment: Bioconductor packages are heavy - my own containers (albeit with Rstudio and shiny server) with few BC packages reach easily 5GB.

Comment: Post the Dockerfile

Comment: I cant upload the docker file but the issue looks like  @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8544044/pszczesny mentioned